# Remove default v-input-file icon in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

[`v-file-input`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs) is a new component that appeared in Vuetify v2.

```
<v-file-input multiple label="File input"></v-file-input>
```

The default behavior shows a prepended icon:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just tried this and it worked:

```
<v-file-input multiple label="File input" prepend-icon=""></v-file-input>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

`<v-file-input multiple label="File input" prepend-icon=""></v-file-input>`

You can disable (or change) it globally in whole app by initializing Vuetify like this:

```js
new Vuetify({
    icons: {
      values: {
        file: ''
      },
    } 
  })
```

See the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#using-custom-icons)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<v-file-input multiple label="File input" :prepend-icon="undefined"></v-file-input>
```

or

```
<v-file-input multiple label="File input" prepend-icon="fancyIconName"></v-file-input>
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work and the second one renders the string itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use :prepend-icon="null"

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `<v-file-input label="file" prepend-icon="" ></v-file-input>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35717196)